# How to use only one element of array for xAxis in jquery.flot.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have a line chart (created with [flot chart](http://www.flotcharts.org/)), which I want to internationalize and for that I need multiple languages for the xAxis labels. My dataTick looks like:

```
{
"itemTicks":
    [
        [24, ["help", "hilfe", "aider"]],
        [3, ["card", "karte", "carte"]],
        [9, ["english", "deutsch", "francaise"]]
    ]
}
```

At the moment it prints eveything out. (So something like: help,hilfe,aider [seperated by commas])
Where can I specify which element/index it should take? And I also want that the user can change the language (e.g. with a selectbox) and the labels should change as well. This already works for the rest of the page which works with a global variable `language` which I set to the index of the wanted language.

I tried to set a formatter on the xAxis, which didn't have any effect:

```
plot = $.plot($('#graph-bars'), series, {
        ...
        xaxis: {
            ticks: itemTicks,
            autoscaleMargin: 0.02,
            labelWidth: 300,
            labelFormatter: function(label, series) {
                return label[0];
            }
        },
        ...
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `label`in your `labelFormatter` function is no longer an array but a string.
So just use the [string.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function like this:

```
return label.split(',')[0];
```